# How can I get the data inside keys of object

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

[image: firebase db]

I try to retrieve the data from the transactions of user id (-m3Jh...) by using the method below.

```
computed: {
    getData() {
        let db = ref.child('transactions/m3JhsTazwgX9AXeYKxYdisSXDob2')
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(s => {
                var arr = s.val()
                console.log(arr)
                console.log(arr[0].title)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

In the console, this result an array of object for each key.

[image]

I just want to retrieve all data inside of each key (-kx...) when I try to console.log arr[0] this result all the 0's object inside of each keys which is not what I want. I just want to retrieve all data inside the specific key or maybe the latest key like in -Kx8h-vJsVtPRekuU8jt this should result all the data inside 0,1,2,3. What I want to implement is just a simple bill that show all the information that the user have ordered. is it much more easier to do with the vuefire?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to map the object to an array of values. Simple example. The second one preserves the keys in the new array.

```
const person = {eyes: {color : 'blue', count: 2},
               feet: { size: 'medium', count: 2},
               hands: { size: 'big', count: 1}};

let oldPerson = Object.keys(person).map(key => person[key]);

let newPerson = Object.assign(...Object.keys(person).map(k => ({[k]: person[k]})));
```

```js
const person = {eyes: {color : 'blue', count: 2},
               feet: { size: 'medium', count: 2},
               hands: { size: 'big', count: 1}};

let oldPerson = Object.keys(person).map(key => person[key]);

let newPerson = Object.assign(...Object.keys(person).map(k => ({[k]: person[k]})));

console.log(oldPerson);
console.log(newPerson);
```